# Serialization of java.util.map and custom pojo in Flink

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am trying to use a pojo which does not implement Serializable from an external library in the kinesis flink application .The serialization is failing while using it inside flatMap function.

Pojo

```
public class ExecutionRecord {
    private Map<String, VariableGroup> factMap;
    private List<ModelResult> models;
    private List<RulesetResult> rulesets;
    private Outcome outcome;
    private ExecutionMetadata executionMetadata;
}
```

Output of `TypeInformation.of(ExecutionRecord.class).toString()`

```
PojoType<ExecutionRecord, fields = [executionMetadata: PojoType<ExecutionMetadata, fields = [endTime: String, evaluationType: String, executionHost: String, executionId: String, gmraInstanceIDs: GenericType<java.util.List>, startTime: String]>, factMap: GenericType<java.util.Map>, models: GenericType<java.util.List>, outcome: PojoType<Outcome, fields = [actions: GenericType<java.util.List>, failedActions: GenericType<java.util.List>, outcomeName: String]>, rulesets: GenericType<java.util.List>]>
```

Error-
`java.io.NotSerializableException: ExecutionRecord`

The stack trace is also not showing which specific field it is not able to serialize.

How shall I register the serializer for `java.util.list` and `java.util.map` which are recognised as generic types and for rest of custom pojos

Comment: Are you using the default serializer (Kyro)? Does `ExecutionRecord` satisfy all the [requirements](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/serialization/types_serialization/#pojos)? (For example I can't see getters for the private fields)

Comment: @PeterCsala I tried by both ways - force enabling Kyro as well letting flink decide.  Yes, those are getting satisfied. The pojo has the public getter , setter for all fields as well as default constructor . I think that why its getting recognized as pojoType from TypeInformation output.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
public static final TypeInformation<ExecutionRecord> TYPE_INFORMATION_POJO = Types.POJO(ExecutionRecord.class);

or

public static final TypeInformation<ExecutionRecord> TYPE_INFORMATION = TypeInformation.of(BehProdViewFLDTO.class);
```

and pass either `TYPE_INFORMATION_POJO` or `TYPE_INFORMATION` to the states or when you may needed!